# Prove the compactness of a set B

Tags: real-analysis

We have $A=\left\lbrace 2019,1010,\ldots,(n+2018)/n,\ldots \right\rbrace$ and $B=A \cup \left\lbrace 1 \right\rbrace$

How can I show directly (that is, not using the compactness criterion in $\mathbb{R}$) that every open cover $G$ of $B$ admits a finite subcover?

moreover, I know that $A$ is not compact and I am aware that I would need a single example to prove it, any hint on how to find an open cover of $A$ that does not contain a finite subcover? 
My first thought was to choose the set of all neighborhoods with radius r centered around each point of A but apparently this is wrong and I do not understand why.

Comment: **Hint:** any open set containing $1$ will contain all but finitely many elements of $A$

Comment: I understand this but now how would I rigorously put this in mathematical terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A = \left\lbrace u_n , \text{ } n \in \mathbb{N}\right\rbrace$, where 
$$u_n = 1 + \frac{2018}{n}$$

The sequence $(u_n)$ tends to $1$. So $B$ is the union of the terms of a convergent sequence and its limit.

Consider an open covering $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ of $B$. One of the $U_i$ contains $1$, denote it by $V$. Because $u_n$ tends to $1$, there exists $N$ such that $u_n \in V$ for all $n \geq N$. Now, for all $k=1, ..., N$, denote by $V_k$ the open $U_i$ in which belongs $u_k$.

It is easy now to see that $V_1, ..., V_N, U$ is a finite subcovering of $B$.

Comment: I understand but aren't you using the compactness criterion in R in this proof? How would I show that any open cover of B has a finite subcover?

Comment: @mrnobody ok, I edited my post.